# Algorithmic complexity: iterating over small bounded list

Tags: time-complexity, computation-theory

My question is sort of about semantics, as well as a little bit about theory vs practice.

Let's say you have a table of items that could be any amount of number.  And let's say you have an array of visible items in the table (items on screen).  The size of the visible cells array is limited by the size of the screen.  This is a known value.  Maybe it will vary from device to device and screen size to screen size, but it is safe to say that it will be a small number, like 20 or less.

Now, if you were to iterate over the visible items, theoretically this is a linear algorithm (iterating over a list of items), however my question is, from a practical software engineering standpoint, is it safe to consider/approximate this algorithm as a constant time algorithm?

Basically, O(n) for n<20 approximates 20 * O(1).

What do you all think?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly correct to consider iterating over 20 or less items as a constant time operation.

Just notice, that the number of visible items is independent of the number of all items in the whole array which is the size of an input. The time complexity is always a function of size of the input.

For example, if you double the size of the input, you still iterate over 20 visible items.